# Export theme from visual studio code to visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to export a theme from visual studio code to visual studio 2015? I like the dark theme in visual studio code and have noticed it has some differences with the dark theme in visual studio 2015 and would like to grab the one from code and use it on 2015.